# WCF WSDL does not expose required classes

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am upgrading an asmx web service into WCF. The asmx wsdl exposes certain classes which are required by the client. The classes are not referenced within the web methods themselves, but they are reference within a class that is within the web methods. For example:

```
WebMethod1(Class1 param)
{
     return Class 2;
}
```

Class1 and Class 2 are included in the wsdl, but any classes that are referenced within Class1 or Class 2 are not included in the WSDL in WCF. However, they were in the asmx WSDL.

Is there any way of exposing these required classes without changing the classes themselves or the code in the web service? I know you can add [DataContract] etc to classes but I find it difficult to believe that WCF should not offer the same power as asmx in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not requiring DataContract is not the power of asmx, or requiring DataContract is not the weakness of WCF. This is by design of WCF for many good reasons, one of which is that you should publish least info to the outside world. For large Web service project, this is a blessing, not restriction. Clients don't want to see the verbose details of your service classes.

A service data class is published through WSDL in order to become a proxy class on the client side only when these conditions are met:

1. The class is decorated by DataContractAttribute, and only properties/data fields decorated by DataMemberAttribute will be published. Nested classes in composite structures will need such decoration as well.
2. The class is referenced in at least one of the operation contracts of service contracts.